# How do I check constraints between two tables when inserting into a third table that references the other two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, check-constraints

Consider this example schema:

```
Customer ( int CustomerId pk, .... )

Employee ( int EmployeeId pk,
           int CustomerId references Customer.CustomerId, .... )

WorkItem ( int WorkItemId pk,
           int CustomerId references Customer.CustomerId,
           null int EmployeeId references Employee.EmployeeId, .... )
```

Basically, three tables:

- A customer table with a primary key and some additional columns
- A employee table with a primary key, a foreign key constraint reference to the customer tables primary key, representing an employee of the customer.
- A work item table, which stores work done for the customer, and also info about the specific employee who the work was performed for.

My question is. How do I, on a database level, test if an employee is actually associated with a customer, when adding new work items.

If for example Scott (employee) works at Microsoft (customer), and Jeff (employee) works at StackOverflow (customer), how do I prevent somebody from adding a work item into the database, with customer = Microsoft, and employee = Jeff, which do not make sense?

Can I do it with check constraints or foreign keys or do I need a trigger to test for it manually?

Should mention that I use SQL Server 2008.

**UPDATE:** I should add that WorkItem.EmployeeId can be null.

Thanks, Egil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't a foreign key on a composite column (CustomerId, EmployeeId) work?

```
ALTER TABLE WorkItem
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Customer_Employee FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId, EmployeeId)
    REFERENCES Employee (CustomerId, EmployeeId);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that WorkItem.EmployeeId can be null. Would the above still work?

Comment: Hmm, not sure; I think some RDBMS can handle that and others can't, and I don't know whether SQL Server can. If not, you could perhaps define a 'No one' employee for each customer. Otherwise a more complex CHECK condition would be needed.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, when I try execute your SQL above, I get the following error message: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Employee' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Customer_Employee'.

Whats missing from my Employee table?

Comment: You need to create a unique index on Employee(EmployeeId, CustomerId). Actually, why isn't that your primary key there?

Comment: @derobert: Good question. It was not a conscious decision on my part, as I mentioned elsewhere, my SQL knowledge is basic. Thanks for the input!

Comment: It seems that Kieron constraint conflicts with the existing foreign key between the Employee table and Customer table. A side note, wonder who voted Kieron's answer down.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this by creating a view "WITH SCHEMABINDING" that spans those tables and enforces the collective constraints of the individual tables.

Comment: +1: Very creative. I had previously never heard of this solution. // This is a perfect example of why Stackoverflow is so cool. I never would've found this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want employeeId to be null int WorkItem? Maybe you should add another table to avoid that particular oddity. From what I can see the easiest thing to do is to add a unique constraint on employeeid in workItem, and maybe even unique on customerId if that is what you want.

A more general way to add constraints spanning many tables is to define a view that should always be empty, and add the constraint that it is empty.

Comment: Sometimes there is no employee associated with a work item, that is why I would like to keep EmployeeId nullable.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to model here?

1. You're a contracting agency or the like, and you have a bunch of contractors who are (for some period of time) assigned to a customer.
2. You're actually storing information about other company's employees (maybe you're providing outsources payroll services, for example).

In case (1), it looks like you have a problem with the `Employee` table. In particular, when Scott's contract with MS is up and he gets contracted to someone else, you can't keep the historical data, because you need to change the `CustomerId`. Which also invalidates all the `WorkItem`s. Instead, you should have a fourth table, e.g., `CustomerEmployee` to store that. Then `WorkItem` should reference that table.

In case (2), your primary key on Employee should really be `CustomerId`, `EmployeeId`. Two customers could have the same employee ID number. Then Kieron's foreign key will work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently pass to a similar situation, consider the schema:
Table company (id_cia PK) Table product_group (id_cia FK to company, id_group PK) Table products (id_group FK to product_group, id_product PK, id_used_by_the_client null)

Rule: The database must allow only one id_used_by_the_client for each product of a company but this filed can be null. Example:

Insert into company (1) = allowed

Insert into company (2) = allowed

Insert into product_group (1, 1) = allowed

Insert into product_group (1,2) = allowed

Insert into product_group (2,3) = allowed

Insert into products values (1, 1, null) = allowed

Insert into products values (1, 2, null) = allowed

Insert into products values (1, 3, 1) = allowed

Insert into products values (1, 4, 1) = not allowed, in the group 1 that belongs to company 1 already exists an id_used_by_the_client = 1.

Insert into products values (2, 4, 1) = not allowed, in the group 2 that belongs to company 1 already exists an id_used_by_the_client = 1.

Insert into products values (3, 4, 1) = allowed, in the group 3 that belongs to company 2 there is no id_used_by_the_client = 1.

I decided to use a trigger to control this integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- make the EmployeeID column the Primary Key of Employee (and possibly an auto-id) and store the EmployeeID in the WorkItem record as a foreign key, instead of storing the Employee and Customer IDs in WorkItem. You can retrieve a WorkItem's Customer details by joining to the Customer table via the Employee table.

Or:

- make the WorkItem's EmployeeID and CustomerID columns a composite foreign key to Employee.

I favour the first approach, personally.

Comment: Your fist approach do not really fit since there is not always an employee associated with a work item. I am not sure if approach two would work in that scenario either.

Comment: Ah, so a WorkItem always has a Customer but may or may not have an Employee?